# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol public: static class std::vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to something very simple and can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > const MazeBuilder::algorithms" (?algorithms@MazeBuilder@@2V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@B)
```

I want to have a vector of strings that I access with my enums so I have a nice way to write out what I'm grabbing, and all my other classes can use it.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "MazeBuilder.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow (QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow (parent), ui (new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi (this);

    //Add available algorithms to the combo box
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MazeBuilder::algorithms.size(); i++)
    {
        ui->algorithmBox->addItem(MazeBuilder::algorithms.at(i).c_str());
    }
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MazeBuilder.cpp

```
#include "MazeBuilder.h"

//Binds to MazeBuilder::MazeAlgorithm
//const static std::vector<std::string> algorithms = {"Prim's"};
const std::vector<std::string> MazeBuilder::algorithms = {"Prim's"};

MazeBuilder::MazeBuilder()
{

}
```

MazeBuilder.h

```
#ifndef MAZEBUILDER_H
#define MAZEBUILDER_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MazeBuilder
{

public:
    enum MazeAlgorithm
    {
        PRIM = 0
    };
    const static std::vector<std::string> algorithms;

    MazeBuilder();
};

#endif // MAZEBUILDER_H
```

ENTIRE PROJECT (SMALL) HERE: https://mega.nz/#!ruoRCZbQ!Jk79ATSO0POb9J_xkaAeNIy9ycVTnHkp1iT4Vq5XFoM

Comment: The comment, in your MazeBuilder.cpp, that states "Binds to MazeBuilder::MazeAlgorithm" is blatantly wrong. The vector _defined_ there is a separate vector called `algorithms`, that has nothing to do with the one _declared_ in MazeBuilder.h. If it was meant to actually be the _definition_ of the one declared in `MazeBuilder` class, the definition would look like `const std::vector<std::string> MazeBuilder::algorithms = {"Prim's"};`

Comment: I changed it to that now, I get the exact same error strangely

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/fz2GzN) your problem, if I use your corrected code. Did you, actually, saved your modifications, and recompiled?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You may find https://wandbox.org/ to be useful.

Comment: Here is my entire project... it is not much larger than what I posted: https://mega.nz/#!ruoRCZbQ!Jk79ATSO0POb9J_xkaAeNIy9ycVTnHkp1iT4Vq5XFoM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. Since `algorithms` is declared as a static *member* of `MazeBuilder` it needs to be defined as such, too. Change its definition in MazeBuilder.cpp to

```
const std::vector<std::string> MazeBuilder::algorithms = {"Prim's"};
```

Otherwise, you're just defining a static variable `algorithms` in the global scope.

The following minimal code compiles and links just fine for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class MazeBuilder {
public:
  const static std::vector<std::string> algorithms;

  MazeBuilder();
};

const std::vector<std::string> MazeBuilder::algorithms = {"Prim's"};
MazeBuilder::MazeBuilder() {
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  for(std::string s : MazeBuilder::algorithms) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made this change a moment ago, I receive the same error after saving and building

Comment: @chibuikem I can't reproduce your issue, after the fix, described in this answer, is applied.

Comment: Here is my entire project... it is not much larger than what I posted: https://mega.nz/#!ruoRCZbQ!Jk79ATSO0POb9J_xkaAeNIy9ycVTnHkp1iT4Vq5XFoM

Comment: Qt Creator was not updating the project correctly... after manually telling it rerun qmake and building it works